# Finding solutions for Real and Imaginary parts of a Complex Number.

Tags: complex-numbers

This is my starting equation for complex number, $ \hat{k} $

$$ \hat{k}^2 = \mu \epsilon \omega - \mu \sigma \omega^2 i $$

I assumed $ \hat{k} = \alpha + \beta i $ where $ \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R} $

I then derived the following:

$$ \alpha^4 - \mu \epsilon \omega \alpha^2 - \frac{1}{4} \mu^2 \sigma^2 \omega^2 = 0 $$

Which gives us four solutions for $ \alpha $.

If we consider $\alpha ^2 = x $ and solve for $ x $, we get 2 solutions.
Griffith's Intro to Electrodynamics (3rd ed.) pg 394, states that these two are only two unique solutions for $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $. And it seems to be the solutions only used the degree 4 equation I am solving above...

But that doesn't make sense,

1. how can we get the solution for $ \beta $ from the equation solving for $ \alpha $?
2. Shouldn't we also consider that there are a total of 8 eight solutions, 4 for $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ each?

How can we then find unique solutions for $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $ ? Does it have to do with the fact that $ \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial equation, namely
$$
k^2 = (\alpha + i\beta)^2 = \alpha^2 - \beta^2 + 2i\alpha\beta = \mu\epsilon\omega - i\mu\sigma\omega^2
$$
is equivalent to the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
   \alpha^2 - \beta^2 &= \mu\epsilon\omega   & (1) \\
   2\alpha\beta       &= -\mu\sigma\omega^2  & (2)
\end{align}
\right.
$$
when separating the real and imaginary parts. The second equation permits to make the substitution
$$
\beta = -\frac{\mu\sigma\omega^2}{2\alpha} \quad\quad (3)
$$
into the first one, hence the biquadratic equation you wrote, i.e.
$$
\alpha^4 - \mu\epsilon\omega\alpha^2 - \frac{1}{4}\mu^2\sigma^2\omega^\color{red}{4} = 0.
$$
So the answer to your first question is simply given by Eq. (3). Now, the above equation is solved (after the algebraic clean-up) by
$$
\alpha_\pm^2 = \frac{1}{2}\mu\epsilon\omega \left(1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon\omega}\right)^2}\right),
$$
hence $\alpha_-^2 < 0$, which is impossible, since it should be a (real) square. In the same spirit, you can exclude another solution when computing $\alpha$ by imposing it to be positive.

---

**Addendum.**
An alternative parametrization of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is represented by the following hyperbolic polar coordinates :
$$
\begin{cases}
   \alpha = \rho\cosh\theta \\
   \beta  = \rho\sinh\theta 
\end{cases}
$$
In consequence, one has :
$$
\begin{cases}
   \rho^2             = \mu\epsilon\omega \\
   \rho^2\sinh2\theta = -\mu\sigma\omega^2
\end{cases}
$$
This system can be solved straightforwardly and possesses the advantage to avoid to generate extraneous solutions $-$ due to the fact that the hyperbolic sinus is bijective and $\rho$ can't be negative obviously, because of its role of radius.

Comment: Solved with thanks! Used the restriction that $ \alpha . \beta < 0 $ to do the final reduction of solutions. Again much thanks for the detailed reply, I shall look into the parametrization..